# Django - How to use the model method in a fuction based view

Tags: django

I have created a function that sums all amounts in a model.

How can I execute this function(get_tot_order_price) in a function based view(FBV)?

def myview(request):
   ???

```
class Cart(TimeStampedModel, models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def get_price(self):
        return self.product.price * self.quantity


class BillingItem(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                         on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Cart)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)

    def get_tot_order_price(self):
        total = 0
        for price in self.products.all():
            total += price.get_price()

        return total
```

Comment: `self.order_price` is a float_field, why are you using `self.order_price.all()`?

Comment: Your `get_tot_order_price`  definitely raise an error.

Comment: Oh sorry. I simply modified the code and it went wrong. I fixed it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `get_tot_order_price` is an instance method. It means you need an instance of `BillingItem` model in order to execute this function. In FBV, you can get an instance then execute this method.

```py
def myview(request):
    obj = BillingItem.objects.get(id=some_id)
    total_price = obj.get_tot_order_price()
```

This will give total_price for a given instance of `BillingItem` model.